# Javascript: map asynchronous function over array, holding execution on each element until it returns on the previous one

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to build a flashcard app, and I have two things: an array with data about each flashcard and an **asynchronous** function that takes in an element of the array and displays the flashcard to the user. As soon as the function is executed, the card is drawn on the screen.

```js
// not actual code, do not debug

const flashcards = [card1, card2, card3] // except way more cards

function showCard(card){
    // immediately draws the card
    // waits for user interaction
    // returns a value when the user is done with the card
}
```

I want to loop over the cards in order, but I want only one card to show at a time. The problem is if I do this:

```js
// not actual code, do not debug

flashcards.forEach((item) => {
    showCard(item)
})
```

...since the function is asynchronous, the browser displays all the flashcards at once, and they get all cluttered and unusable on the screen.

How can I loop over the cards in such a way that each card is drawn only after the user is done interacting with the previous card (i.e., when showCard returns)?

Comment: So just to be sure. `showCard` returns a promise that is resolved after the user is done interacting with the card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're looking for an async solution but instead a flag to wait for user interaction.

Something like:

```
let currentCardIndex = 0;

while (currentCardIndex < flashcards.length) {

    showCard(flashcards[currentCardIndex]);
    currentCardIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches here you could either:

1. Spawn a promise and wait for a return value from using thenable semantics.
2. Pass a callback too which call with the return value when the user is done with UI
3. Event emitter to emit that a card has been processed with a return value.

### Promise

Pseudocode for promise based solution

```js
let aCardIsVisible = false
function onShowFlashcardHandler (cardId) {
  // a card is already visible return
  if (aCardIsVisible) {
    return
  }

  const card = flashcards.find(card => card.id === cardId)
  if (card) {
    // toggle on flag
    aCardIsVisible = true
    showCard(card)
     .then(value => {
       // do something with return value
  
       // toggle off flag
       aCardIsVisible = false
     })
  }
}


function showCard (card) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // draw card 
    // on some UI input or timeout loop for checking UI changes
    loop :=
      if UI done then
        value <- UI input value
        resolve(value)
      end
    endloop
  })
}
```

### Callback

Pseudocode for callback based solution

```js
let aCardIsVisible = false
function onShowFlashcardHandler (cardId) {
  // a card is already visible return
  if (aCardIsVisible) {
    return
  }

  const card = flashcards.find(card => card.id === cardId)
  if (card) {
    // toggle on flag
    aCardIsVisible = true
    showCard(card, (value) => {
       // do something with return value
  
       // toggle off flag
       aCardIsVisible = false
    })
  }
}


function showCard (card, callback) {
  // draw card 
  // on some UI input or timeout loop for checking UI changes
  loop :=
    if UI done then
      value <- UI input value
      callback(value)
    end
  endloop
}
```

### Event emitter or Custom Events

Pseudocode for event emitter or custom events based solution
This assumes you either use a [event emitter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) or [custom events](https://github.com/sindresorhus/emittery)

```js
let aCardIsVisible = false
function onShowFlashcardHandler (cardId) {
  // a card is already visible return
  if (aCardIsVisible) {
    return
  }

  const card = flashcards.find(card => card.id === cardId)
  if (card) {
    // toggle on flag
    aCardIsVisible = true
    showCard(card)
    
  }
}

function onCardDone (value) {
  // do something with return value
  
  // toggle off flag
  aCardIsVisible = false
}


function showCard (card) {
  // draw card 
  // on some UI input or timeout loop for checking UI changes
  loop :=
    if UI done then
      value <- UI input value
      emitter.emit('cardDone', value) // event emitter
      element.dispatchEvent('cardDone', value) // custom event
    end
  endloop
}
```